# Insert child in general tree in C

Tags: c

I'm new at learning general trees with this kind of struct.

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *Child; // hijo
    struct Node *nextSibling; // hno
}
```

(GTree is the pointer to Nodo)

And I have a problem that I can't insert any child at all and I don't know why. Can I get some help?

```
GTree gtree_crear() {
    return NULL;
}
GTree gtree_agregar(GTree arbol, void *datoPadre, void *dato, FuncionCopiadora copiar, FuncionComparadora comp){
    if(arbol == NULL){
        arbol = malloc(sizeof(struct _GTNodo));
        arbol->dato = copiar(dato);
        arbol->hijo = gtree_crear();
        arbol->hno = gtree_crear();
    }
    else if (comp(datoPadre, arbol->dato) == 0){
        GTree copia = arbol->hijo;
        for(; copia != NULL; copia = copia->hno);
        copia = gtree_agregar(copia, datoPadre, dato, copiar, comp);
    }
    else{
      for(GTree arbol_copia = arbol->hno; arbol_copia != NULL; arbol_copia = arbol_copia->hno) arbol_copia = gtree_agregar(arbol->hno, datoPadre, dato, copiar, comp);
      for(GTree arbol_copia = arbol->hijo; arbol_copia != NULL; arbol_copia = arbol_copia->hno) arbol_copia = gtree_agregar(arbol->hno, datoPadre, dato, copiar, comp);
    }
    return arbol;
}
```

The problem is when I reach the father (else if) and can't add the child. I tried to make a copy of the pointer of the tree (GTree copia), go to the last child (for) and add it there but it doesn't modify the tree whatsoever.

Comment: "but it doesn't modify the tree whatsoever" Well, yout statements like `copia = gtree_agregar(...)` modify local variables, they will not modify the tree. In order to modify the tree you probably want to have the tree to the left of `=`. Perhaps something like `arbol -> ... = ...`.

Comment: You should get used to select English-only identifiers. You *will* at some point of time share your code with non-hispanophones – and if only here on SO – and these only can guess the meaning of functions, variables or structs with Spanish identifiers. Apart from, this wild language mixture is anything but aesthetic...

Comment: Don't typedef pointers, this is only hiding away information without any further value.